# How to simulate mouse and keyboard to operate an application from a WinForm program?

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, mouse, simulation

I am writing a WinForm program in C#, to move mouse cursor, click mouse, stroke keyboard, to operate another running GUI application in Windows.
Is this possible, how to do it? I mean the simulation of mouse and keyboard and operation of another GUI application.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't really answer the direct question, but [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) would be perfect for a task like this.

Answer (score 1):

[`SendInput`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendInput) is your friend here.  It doesn't have a direct C# wrapper, but it's easy to use with P/Invoke.

SendInput places input into the input queue, which then gets dispatched normally, so you will need to set focus to the target application first.